# How to convert a MULE encoded file to UTF-8?

Tags: character-encoding, unicode, perl, utf-8

I am trying to modify a buffer written by [`desktop-save`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html#Saving-Emacs-Sessions) to a file. The file is named `.emacs.desktop` and I am trying to modify it from a Perl script. It turns out that it is saved in `emacs-mule` encoding.

From `M-x list-coding-systems` :

```
U -- utf-8 (alias: mule-utf-8)
  UTF-8 (no signature (BOM))
M -- emacs-mule
  Emacs 21 internal format used in buffer and string.
```

I would like to read the file in Perl as `UTF-8`, how can this be done?
(I would prefer a solution that does not depend on a running Emacs server)

(An example: `emacs-mule` saves the letter `æ` as two bytes `0x81 0xe6`, ISO Latin 1 saves it as a single byte `0xe6`, whereas UTF-8 saves it as two bytes `0xc3 0xa6`.. )

Comment: Can `M-x revert-buffer-with-coding-system` help?

Comment: @Name Yes it seems like I have to consider options for doing the conversion from within Emacs.. I could not find any Perl modules that can convert between MULE and UTF-8.. so currently, it seems only Emacs knows how to do the conversion. The drawback with this approach is that the Perl script needs to rely on running a new Emacs instance in batch mode..

Comment: I am not sure if the problem discussed in this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/627661/ is related to your question but it is worth looking at.

Comment: You might be able to dig the details of the `emacs-mule` coding out of the file [src/coding.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/coding.c) in the emacs source code. There are extensive comments in that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I ended up with:

- Assume an Emacs server with name `my_server` is up and running.
- Convert `emacs-mule` to `utf-8` by calling `emacsclient` from the Perl script:

  ```
  emacsclient -s my_server -e '(my-convert-mule-utf8 \".emacs.desktop\")' >/dev/null 2>&1`
  ```

where `my-convert-mule-utf8` is

```el
(defun my-convert-mule-utf8 (fn)
  (let*  ((temp-fn (concat fn ".utf8"))
         (coding-system-for-write 'utf-8))
    (with-temp-file temp-fn
      (insert-file-contents fn)
      (when (re-search-forward "coding: \\(emacs-mule\\);" (line-end-position) t)
        (replace-match "utf-8" nil t nil 1)))))
```

- To convert `utf-8` to `emacs-mule`:

  ```
  emacsclient -s my_server -e '(my-convert-utf8-mule \".emacs.desktop\")' >/dev/null 2>&1
  ```

where `my-convert-utf8-mule` is:

```el
(defun my-convert-utf8-mule (fn)
  (let* ((temp-fn (concat fn ".utf8"))
         (coding-system-for-write 'emacs-mule))
    (with-temp-file fn
      (insert-file-contents temp-fn)
      (when (re-search-forward "coding: \\(utf-8\\);" (line-end-position) t)
        (replace-match "emacs-mule" nil t nil 1)))))
```